# How is the definition of heat kernels generalized to operators acting on $\mathbf{R}^n$-valued functions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

If we consider an operator $A\colon C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^n,\mathbf{R})\to C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^n,\mathbf{R})$, the heat kernel is a function
$$k\colon (0,\infty)\times\mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$$
satisfying
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}k+Ak=0
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\lim_{t \to 0}\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} k(t,x,y)\phi(y)\,dy = \phi(x)
\end{equation}
for all test functions $\phi\colon \mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$.$^1$

Now consider an operator $H\colon C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^m,\mathbf{R}^n)\to C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^m,\mathbf{R}^n)$. To generalize ($2$), the heat kernel needs to be a function $$Q\colon (0,\infty)\times\mathbf{R}^m\times\mathbf{R}^m\to\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$$
but then it is not clear how to generalize ($1$) since the expression $HQ$ is not defined.

---

$^1$ In ($1$), $Ak\colon (0,\infty)\times\mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$ is defined by $(Ak)(t,x,y):=(Ak(t,\,\cdot\,,y))(x)$

Comment: A tad slow here, but why is $Q$ mapping into $R^{n\times n}$ rather than $R$?

Comment: @Aruralreader I think I just found an answer to my question. At the same time, I realized that my "generalization" of the definition of the heat kernel of the Laplacian to other operators acting on real valued functions (the first paragraph of my question) is not correct. I need to go to sleep now, but I'll add an answer when I wake up.

Comment: @Aruralreader In case you are interested, I added the answer.

Comment: @Aruralreader Regarding your initial question: I cannot give a good answer, but I can confirm that this is how the heat kernel is generalized.

Answer (score 1):

The generalization is straightforward if one knows the correct definition of heat kernels. Equation $(1)$ was supposed to generalize the definition of the [heat kernel of the Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel), but the heat kernel is actually defined by the following property (in the case of the Laplacian, it can be shown that $(1)$ implies this property):

> Consider some test function $\phi_0\in C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^n,\mathbf{R})$. Then the family
> $$\phi\colon(0,\infty)\to C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^n,\mathbf{R})$$
> defined by
> $$\phi_t(x)=\int k(t,x,y)\phi(y) dy$$
> is the solution to the heat equation with initial state $\phi_0$:
> \begin{equation}
> \dot{\phi}+A\phi=0\land \lim_{t\to 0}\phi_t=\phi_0
> \end{equation}